# Simple upload multiple images in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to do a simple upload in my system, just with the `multiple="true"` input property.
Actually, I have 15 file inputs, and they all rename the file name to: 'id.in.the.bd'_'number'.jpg (Ex.: 65_1.jpg). Like this:

**HTML**

```
    // inside a form
    <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) { ?>
       <input name="foto_<?php echo $x; ?>" type="file" id="foto" multiple="true" />
    <?php } ?>
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "insert") {


//sql insert


// do a consult to find the $id
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imoveis ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", $link); 

$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$id = $result['id'];

for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) {
   $file = $_FILES["foto_" . $x];
   $path = '../../images/galeria/' . $id . '_' . $x . '.jpg';
   move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $path);
}
```

How can I easily change my code to use the `multiple="true"`? If I just change the `input` to `multiple="true"`, he just upload the first image selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the input tags to

```
<input name="foto[]" id="foto_1" type="file" />
```

In PHP these files are accessible by $_FILES['foto']['name'] array, like this:

```
$_FILES['foto']['name'][0] for file 1
$_FILES['foto']['name'][1] for file 2
```

etc..

Comment: for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) {
         $_FILES['foto']['name'][0] for file 1;
         $_FILES['foto']['name'][0] for file 2;
         $_FILES['foto']['name'][0] for file 3;
         $_FILES['foto']['name'][0] for file 4;
         $path = '../../images/galeria/' . $id . '_' . $x . '.jpg';
         move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $path);
     }

Comment: Ignore the "for file .." this is a comment.. Acesse o array igual antes, só que em vez de tmp_name conter o nome, conterá o array de nomes. etc..

Comment: Tentei assim, para apenas 4 fotos, mas ele não está salvando a imagem:
for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) {
         $_FILES['foto']['name'][0];
         $_FILES['foto']['name'][1];
         $_FILES['foto']['name'][2];
         $_FILES['foto']['name'][3];
         $path = '../../images/galeria/' . $id . '_' . $x . '.jpg';
         move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $path);
     }

Comment: for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($_FILES['foto']['name']); $x++) { $path = '../../images/galeria/' . $id . '_' . $x . '.jpg'; move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"][$x], $path); }